# Unity game resolution lowered

Tags: unity, resolution

I recently upgraded unity from 2018.1 to 2018.2 and also upgraded my nvidia geforce.

I have seen that the letters resolution of the program itself are better now but my game tab is going lower res then before.

In the image I attached you can see the difference between the game emulation on game tab (windows) and the scene tab

The girl on the scene tab looks much smoother and better then how it appears on the game tab , before updating these were the same look and resolution.

Is there some options that control resolution of game tab in unity? (resolution as in dpi not in width and height)

Thanks[image]

Comment: I've noticed that the scale in your game window is set to `x1.25` which scaled the game up, but even despite of that, is a build of your game suffering from this as well? If not, then there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to some friends, I have found the answer and thought I'd post it for others.
Unity 2018.2 seems like it has a new option called : "Low Aspect Resolution Aspect" that can be found in the game tab under Free Aspect (or something else if you have set it) which is next to Display.